# How to open Microsoft Team or OneDrive File Screen using URI or intent from my App

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am integrating ms teams feature in my app using ms graph API, i have successfully open chat calendar and call feature using deeplink URI, Now i want to open files directory using Intent or URI in MS team app install in my devices`
how to lunch Files screen of MS team from my app, or using URI.

Comment: Hi @Shoaib, Can you share more details on which files you want to open ? Are these files part of teams channels ? You can refer below link for more reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-deep-links-to-file-in-channel

Comment: @shoaib - Could you please share repro steps so that we can check it from our end.

Comment: I want to view screen for all files folder, not a specific file. Simply i want to navigate user from my app to teams files screen

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar - Could you please share the deeplink which you are trying.

Comment: i was trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-deep-links-to-file-in-channel but i dont want to open specific file, or file in channel i want to show user all his file folders

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no deeplink or method available that will redirect user to files tab. The only option available is to deeplink to specific file.

Thanks